# How can I convert record to string in Mozart OZ

Tags: type-conversion, oz, mozart

For example:

```
local A = aircraft(id:'Avro' size:[2 36] state:state(time:20 status:parked))           
in
  {Browse A}
end
```

I would like to convert A to string like Browse window in order to send the data to other program via pipe (serializing).

Exist any Mozart native function or any short way? 
Thanks for your ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the library function `Value.toVirtualString`([docs](http://www.mozart-oz.org/documentation/base/node3.html)). For `DepthI` and `WidthI` you just chose some large integer value if you don't want to limit the output.

To make sure that the result is a string (not a virtual string), use `VirtualString.toString`.